# AST Golang, функция Walk, принцип работы

Tags: парсер, golang, дерево

Хочу понять работу функции [Walk](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4517c02f284cc19262304ba22c1c98b2bbdb0208/src/go/ast/walk.go#L51) и паттерна [Visitor](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4517c02f284cc19262304ba22c1c98b2bbdb0208/src/go/ast/walk.go#L12), а также паттерна [Inspect](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/4517c02f284cc19262304ba22c1c98b2bbdb0208/src/go/ast/walk.go#L384). Как я читал в одной [статье](https://zupzup.org/go-ast-traversal/) при помощи функции `Walk` можно обходить с легкостью АСД, но я смотрю на код и ничего не догоняю, зачем вообще эта функция нужна, они же по сути ничего не делает, ничего не возвращает, рекурсивно обходит ноду и всё, дерево не сдвигает, как бы "пустой" принцип работы лично для меня. Можно же сделать просто `for _, x := range node.Decls {}`, понять при помощи ассерта какой тип ноды, допустим `SwitchExpr` или `IfExpr` или `AssignExpr`, потом печатать ноду и её данные в зависимости от ноды всё. К чему эти функции не пойму, но очень-очень хочу понять, так как сам пишу парсер, объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: посмотрите на ассемблерный вариант фора и этой функции ради интереса, и вы поймете почему там не используют цикл... насколько я знаю функции с циклами или редко или вообще никогда не инлайнятся в го (хотя я могу ошибаться). Вы можете попробовать сделать альтернативу на goto но я не уверен будет ли быстрей))

Comment: @noname2019 так вопрос не об этом, я понимаю что там всё очень печально, но меня интересует то что делает функция `Walk`, а как я посмотрел в код она ничего не делает, а рекурсивно проходит по массиву нод и всё.

Comment: Ну да, она делает это, чтобы вам не пришлось.  Необходима ли эта функция?  Нет.  Удобно ли, что она есть?  Да.

Comment: @Ainar-G это сарказм? абсолютно не понимаю о чем вы.

Comment: `Walk` -- это обход синтаксического дерева. Что в этом не понятно? `range Decls{}` -- а это тут вообще ни при чём. AST -- дерево. Decls там сбоку.

Comment: @IvanBlack я прекрасно понимаю что обходит, но какой от этого смысл, если Walk рекурсивно обходит дерево без каких либо действий. ```range Decls{}``` я взял попросту для примера.

Comment: Ну так а какие там должны быть действия? Range что-то делает что ли? Чего вообще от дерева надо?

Answer (score 0):

Друже, если ты еще не нашел ответ, попробую тебе угодить.
Раз ты пишешь, что не видишь никакого смысла в этой процедуре, значит, наверняка не понял в ней вот этого (самого первого) кусочка:

```go
if v = v.Visit(node); v == nil {
        return
    }
```

теперь поясняю, Walk действительно обходит все ветки дерева, но не просто так, для каждой ноды выполняется Visit интерфейса Visitor. Для чего это?
Вот представь, что тебе нужно обойти какой то код и найти в нем все места, где используется переменная такая то (ну не знаю - любая) но при этом в коде нет ее инициализации (объявление есть, использование есть, но нет инициализации)
ну совсем такой пример... прости
я просто хочу сказать, что тебе не просто нужно просмотреть каждую ноду, но и учитывать состояние кода по пути до нее, а так же не путать эти состояния и состояния, которые будут в коде вне блоков с этой нодой. ну ветвления, конструкции и прочее

так вот с помошью интерфейса Visitor и этого Walk ты можешь это с легкостью сделать! Для каждой ноды будет вызвана процедура Visit твоего Visitor и не просто так, а с запоминанием состояний каждой новой ветки. т.е. прикинь, что Walk входит в ветку IfExpr или любую другую ветку, ты можешь сохранять какие то состояния в своем Visitor и они будут доступны во всех нодах этой ветки, но! Как только Walk выйдет из ветки, все состояния этой ветки будут сброшены и это хорошо, потому, что область видимости уничтожена.

Как бы тебе объяснить картинкой...
прошу прощения за дурацкий пример и, может быть, непонятное объяснение, но глянь сюда:
https://gist.github.com/iv-menshenin/78a6f1cfc1126e4ab853e5dc8342be08
тут мы обходим такой код (комменты 1,2 и 3 я объясню ниже):

```
func test() {
    var i string
    if (true) { // 1
        var i *int // 2
        for {
            *i++
        }
    } // 3
    i += "done"
    return i
}
```

а в выводе видим:

```
... ... ...
----------------
ref variables: i
<*ast.GenDecl>: &{Doc:<nil> TokPos:61 Tok:var Lparen:0 Specs:[0xc00008a140] Rparen:0}
&{pass:true names:[0xc00000c1a0]}
это когда мы зашли в сектор 2
прошу заметить, что в секторе 1 у нас появилась копия нашего Walker,
которая будет хранить состояние кода до того, как мы попали внутрь if (true) // 2
----------------
... ... ...
----------------
PANIC! USAGE OF REF: i
ref variables: i
<*ast.Ident>: i
&{pass:false names:[0xc00000c1a0]}
ага! а вот сработала паника, мы нашли использование ссылочной переменной  
на самом деле я реализовал пример не полностью, еще бы при обнаружении инициализации,  
нужно удалять из names нашу переменную... но суть не в реализации
----------------
<*ast.AssignStmt>: &{Lhs:[i] TokPos:98 Tok:+= Rhs:[0xc00000c2e0]}
&{pass:false names:[]}
посмотри, куда девалось все names? а все просто - мы вышли из блока if (true) // 2
и теперь наше состояние вернулось у тому, что было в секторе 1  
ведь область видимости с переменной типа *int теперь недоступна  
и Walk понимает это и очищает ее за тебя
----------------
... ... ...
----------------
<*ast.ReturnStmt>: &{Return:109 Results:[i]}
&{pass:false names:[]}
----------------
<*ast.Ident>: i
&{pass:false names:[]}
ну и эта переменная i - это строковая (судя по коду)
поэтому нет PANIC
----------------
```

итак, нормальными словами: 
это простой обход каждого узла синтаксического дерева с учетом областей видимости